# Weblogic12c to configure SAML SSO with ADFS

Tags: saml, weblogic12c, adfs

I have a problem as below::

1. I have the application A(A is Java web application). The app A using sale the GUN for the customer.
   In-App A, The user has a role:
   -S(Salesperson): This is the normal user.

   - M(Manager): Allow the user approve when Salesperson transfer GUN to customer.
2. App A is deployed on Weblogic 12C.
3. On Weblogic, I am using SMALL to integrate with ADFS (ADFS: Active Directory Federation Services)
4. In the first time, the Salesperson access to application A. Weblogic is redirecting to the login page of ADFS.
   After login success, Weblogic will redirect to A application.
5. The app A is login success.
6. Continue, Salesperson is transfer GUN for the customer. When Salesperson is transferring, I need to the manager to approve. 
   Therefore, I need to display the login form to the Manager login.
7. After Manager login success, if the user has a role is M, the sale person can transfer the gun for the customer. Else, I have a display error message.

My Problem:
Step 6: How can I display the login page of ADFS?
Step 7: How can I check the role of the user after login success?

Can you help me out? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have one application, you can't do this.

Only one person can be logged in at a time.

After that, the cookie says the user is authenticated so you don't get another login screen.

Run the application in two different browsers.

Then when the manager opens his browser, he will be asked to login.

**Update**

Each application is a relying party (RP) in ADFS. Each RP has its own set of cookies so they don't clash.

So configure e.g. two RP in ADFS, one for each application.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I have more an application, How I can resolve my problem?